# JQuery click() method how to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping

I'm making a webscraper and I'm already having some nice data but now I would loop on the pages.

EDIT: I'm using nodeJS

I already know than I've 10 pages so I've making a simple code like this :

```
while (nbrPage > 0)
{
    //my scraping code
    nbrPage--;
    $('.next').click();
}
```

Note than the html code to scrape is like this :

```
<span class="next">
     <a id="nextPage-159c6fa8635" class="page" href="/blablabla"></a>
</span>
```

When I'm running my this code is my nodeJS command prompt I've this error : `TypeError: $(...).click is not a function`

Unfortunately the `<a>`'s id (nextPage-...) is changing or each pages.

Does anyone know what is wrong in my code and what I have to do ?

Thanks community

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method from jQuery

```
while (nbrPage > 0)
{
    //my scraping code
    nbrPage--;
    $('.next').find('a').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sysix for your answer, unfortunately I've also this error TypeError: $(...).find(...).trigger is not a function

Comment: It seems you didn't load jQuery.

Comment: I'm using nodeJS, do you know what I've to do ?

Comment: @rastafalow nodejs is a backend framework, in frontend you have to use jquery regulary.

Comment: I'm using nodeJS because I use very useful tools like request and cheerio. Do you have any solution for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using core javascript:

1. Using callback function:

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.next');

test.onclick=function(){
alert('click');
}
```

```html
<span class="next">
     <a>click</a>
</span>
```

OR
2.Using Event Listener

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.next');

test.addEventListener('click',function(){
alert('click');
});
```

```html
<span class="next">
     <a>click</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hikmat for your answer but I want to click on the button, I don't want to handle the event. I'm also using nodeJS...

Comment: @rastafalow just replace anchor tag with button in html.But sorry im null in node js...no idea brother.

Answer (score 0):

you can just attach jQuery `click` event handler to use it

```js
$("#click-btn").on('click', function() {
  alert(this.id + ' is clicked !!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="click-btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Hi @sa77 I'm using nodeJS and I'm scraping a web page. I would make a click, I don't want to handle the click event. Do you have any solution ?